# Sorting a multidimentional array and moving all the same values to the last array in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on a primitive graphic for the inventory
that shows how much space is currently taken and how much theres
left.

It does this by showing 5 rows of 20 squares
(Gray = free space, yellow =space taken).

Now, my problem is that I want to find all values that
are 1 and put them in the last array.

So that the array goes from:

```
var myMap:Array = [
            [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
            ];
```

to

```
   var myMap:Array = [
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
            ];
```

Basically I want to sort the entire array so that all zero's come first
and all 1's get put in the last one till its full, then the second last one and so on.

I'm away I will most likely need an algorithm for this but I am hoping theres an easier way to do this. I'm usually a C# developer so AS3 is not my strongest suit.

hopefully someone understood what I ment and can help me, its 4:30 am, so I might not be as lucid as I'd like.

~Thanks

*EDIT*

Added the code so people can get more of a informed look:

Keep in mind most of the names and so on are placeholders, currently I just need it working.

```
private function _showInventoryGraphic()
        {
            var mapWidth = 20;
            var mapHeight = 5;
            var myMap:Array = [
            [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
            ];
            var posX:int = 15;
            var posY:int = 15;
            var startPosY:int = 250;
            for (var i:int=0; i<mapHeight; i++)
            {
                for (var u:int = 0; u < mapWidth; u++)
                {
                    if (myMap[i][u] == 0)
                    {
                        var grayRect:Shape = new Shape;
                        grayRect.graphics.beginFill(0x808080);
                        grayRect.graphics.drawRect(posX*u, startPosY, 10,10);
                        grayRect.graphics.endFill();
                        addChild(grayRect);
                    }
                    if (myMap[i][u] == 1)
                    {
                        var yellowRect:Shape = new Shape;
                        yellowRect.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF00);
                        yellowRect.graphics.drawRect(posX*u, startPosY, 10,10);
                        yellowRect.graphics.endFill();
                        addChild(yellowRect);
                    }
                }
                startPosY += posY;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is it possible to cheat and just count the number of 1's and generat your result array from that?

Comment: Well, I suppose, but the problem is that the array's will be changing all the time, the items that's in the inventory will be sold with each turn as well as new items will be added whenever the player buys new things. So that would mean I would have to remake the array each time an item gets sold or added. Which does not seem like a very good idea.

Comment: You mean the 2d array itself will keep changing size or just the contents? Another idea may be to simplify this a bit perhaps flatten the 2d array in to a 1d array and sort as usual. Or keep pointers to the first and last empty slot and swap once a new item is added/removed and update the pointers.

Comment: Its the contents, but the problem is that I need a 2d array for the graphic. I draw the inventory as you would a tilemap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying it out from a few different approaches, I think the biggest challenge is the fact that it is a 2d array.

The first attempt was similar, but like quicksort, where there were 2 pointers at either end of the 2d array and they moved 'inwards' looking for a scenario where the first pointer was a '1' and the last pointer was a '0' and swapping the two, until the pointers met in the 'middle'. I gave up on this method while trying to properly decrement and increment the linear counters in a 2d array. =b

The second attempt was by keeping track of the last index in the array that was as empty and the last index in the array that was full. Then within the addItem and removeItem methods I'd put the item in the correct spot and update the counters to avoid a sort. This seemed to work, but maybe a bit messy and perhaps harder to maintain in the future. It sorts the result in separate arrays.

In the third attempt for a 'direct sort', I think the most simple way then is just flatten the array apart in to a 2d array, sort it, then rejoin it. You would be correct in that this is not the most efficient method, though one thing to consider is how often this needs to run and how efficient it really needs to be given the context. I *think* a 2d array of only 100 elements is not too big of an issue to use an inefficient sort method?

Maybe someone else can come up with better/cleaner methods. =b

Below is code for what I mentioned.

Second attempt (Note: I did not test this one fully, but it seemed to work):

```
import flash.geom.Point;

var unsortedMap:Array = [
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                        ];

var sortedMap:Array = [
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                        ];

var rowSize:int = unsortedMap[0].length;
var rowCount:int = unsortedMap.length;

// points to the last index at start, since want to have filled items at the 'end'
var emptySpotPointer:Point = new Point(rowSize - 1, rowCount - 1);
var fullSpotPointer:Point = new Point(rowSize - 1, rowCount - 1);

function print2dArray(prefix:String, input:Array):void {
    trace(prefix);
    for(var row:String in input){
        trace("\t"+ input[row]);
    }
    trace("");
}


function addItem(inputX:int, inputY:int):void {
    if(unsortedMap[inputY][inputX] == 1){
        trace("addItem() - Already an item here: "+ inputX +", "+ inputY);
        return;
    }
    trace("addItem() - Adding an item: "+ inputX +", "+ inputY);

    unsortedMap[inputY][inputX] = 1;
    sortedMap[emptySpotPointer.y][emptySpotPointer.x] = 1;
    fullSpotPointer.x = emptySpotPointer.x;
    fullSpotPointer.y = emptySpotPointer.y;

    if(emptySpotPointer.x == 0){
        emptySpotPointer.x = rowSize - 1;
        emptySpotPointer.y--;

    } else {
        emptySpotPointer.x--;
    }
}


function removeItem(inputX:int, inputY:int):void {
    if(unsortedMap[inputY][inputX] == 0){
        trace("removeItem() - No item here to remove: "+ inputX +", "+ inputY);
        return;
    }
    trace("removeItem() - Removing an item here: "+ inputX +", "+ inputY);

    unsortedMap[inputY][inputX] = 0;
    sortedMap[fullSpotPointer.y][fullSpotPointer.x] = 0;

    if(fullSpotPointer.x == (rowSize - 1)){
        fullSpotPointer.x = 0;
        fullSpotPointer.y++;

    } else {
        fullSpotPointer.x++;
    }
}



// testing stuff here
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
function addRandomitems():void {
    var randomX:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * rowSize);
    var randomY:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCount);
    addItem(randomX, randomY);
}

function removeRandomitems():void {
    var randomX:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * rowSize);
    var randomY:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * rowCount);
    removeItem(randomX, randomY);
}

print2dArray("unsortedMap", unsortedMap);
print2dArray("sortedMap", sortedMap);

trace("Test: Adding items now ---------------------");
var counter:int = 0;
for(counter = 0; counter < 50; counter++){
    addRandomitems();
    print2dArray("unsortedMap", unsortedMap);
    print2dArray("sortedMap", sortedMap);
}

trace("Test: Removing items now ---------------------");
for(counter = 0; counter < 50; counter++){
    removeRandomitems();
    print2dArray("unsortedMap", unsortedMap);
    print2dArray("sortedMap", sortedMap);
}
```

Third attempt:

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;

var myMap:Array = [
            [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
            ];

function sort(inputArray:Array):Array {
    var rowSize:int = inputArray[0].length;

    var flat:Array = new Array();

    // flattening the array here
    for(var row:String in inputArray){
        flat = flat.concat(inputArray[row]);
    }
    flat.sort();

    var result:Array = new Array();

    // recreating the original array here by cutting out 'rowSize' chunks and reforming the 2d array
    while(flat.length > 0){
        result.push(new Array(flat.splice(0, rowSize)));
    }
    return result;
}

// testing
var startTimer:int = flash.utils.getTimer();
for(var counter:int = 0; counter < 10000; counter++){
    sort(myMap);
}

// Running the above 10,000 times takes 1836ms for me.
trace(flash.utils.getTimer() - startTimer);

// just to see the output:
trace(sort(myMap).join("\n"));
```

Comment: For some reason it only sorts them in the trace "trace(sort(myMap).join("\n"));", it refuses to sort them outside the trace. If I write "sort(myMap)" or "sort(myMap).join("\n");" neither of them sorts it. Also it only SHOWS the sorted array in the trace, it never actually sorts it.

Comment: Nevermind, its me being stupid. "myMap = sort(myMap)" fixed it. Thanks a bunch.